# Is it possible to debug TinyMCE editor live against it's source code in JS?

Tags: javascript, debugging, tinymce

I've found small bug in tinymce styleselect. I've submitted bugreport already (http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/develop/bugtracker_view.php?id=4576) but I need the fix fast. Is it possible to debug TinyMCE editor live against it's source code?

I've been looking for some how-to and in documentation and the only thing I can do with TinyMCE source codes is to actually build them.

How can I debug tinyMCE with developer version downloaded? Even when I use this version I'm not able to debug it anyhow.

Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you nee is to include the file `tiny_mce_dev.js` istead of `tiny_mce.js`  . For further results use firebug (+console.log('...'); + console.trace();) or a something similar and debugging is fun.

Comment: I've tried _src.js version - did not helped. And _dev.js version did not work ...

Comment: Thank you. I was expected to include tiny_mce_src.js as editor script setting to tinymce initialization and to include separated script tiny_mce_dev.js. Then I can debug with non-obfuscated source code.

Comment: i do not know what the file tiny_mce_src.js is good for, but a colleague of mine made the same mistake just today :)

Comment: It looks like the _src.js file is and uncompressed version of tiny_mce.js After creating a patch I'm now trying to build it with ant, but there is some problem with yuicompress-or. But, I'll solve it somehow (i hope).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I get you right. What do you mean - is it possible to debug? Is you question actually about possibility to debug without inserting debug statement directly in tinymce's core javascript files? Since, for good or for bad, it is the best option to debug big pieces of js code.

You can also add breakpoint in tinymce code (via debugger; expression in code directly, or using some browser development tool, firebug is good example).

Comment: To add breakpoint in tinymce code is exactly what I want to do. Bud I can't do it because even using development version of tinymce with sources, the source file isn't accessible from firebugs (or other browser development tool).

Comment: @Crank, the source code is always accessible in firebug if you can see an instance of tinymce editor in your browser's window. Check for script tab in firebug, then select specific file, than click at line number in source code - you'll see a red circle.  Or is code obfuscated or something?

Comment: Thanks @shabunc . I've already tried this and I cannot see proper sources available in scripts tab. Only few editor_plugin.js's which are actually obfuscated. As Thariama mentioned, I've tried to use also tiny_mce_dev.js and tiny_mce_src.js and nothing helped. (_dev version actually did not work)